# Fixed div moving on scroll in iOS & Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fixed

I've got a weird bug happening with a fixed position div scrolling on mobile devices.

Here's the markup...

```
<div class="col-sm-6 hidden-md hidden-lg mobile-cart-wrapper" id="mobile-cart-wrapper">
     <div class="mobile-cart" id="mobile-cart">
           {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" return="account/cart"}
                <div class="add-to-cart">
                    <button class="btn btn-white full-width" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>ADD</button>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center item-qty">
                    <label>
                      Qty <input type="number" name="item_qty" value="">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {if country_seg == 'ca'}
                        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{country_seg}_product_price}">
                        <span class="cost">{{country_seg}_product_price}</span>
                    {if:else}
                        <span class="cost">{price}</span>
                    {/if}
                </div>
            {/exp:store:product}
    </div>
```

I am using some bootstrap classes here to only show this block if we are in a small screen size or lower. Also, I am using some custom CSS and JS to make this block scroll to fixed once it gets near the top of the screen.

Here is the JS...

```
    var viewport = $(window);
    var cart = $('.mobile-cart');
    var cartTop = cart.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll($.throttle(75, floatingAddToCart));
    $(window).resize($.throttle(75, floatingAddToCart));

    function floatingAddToCart () {
        viewport = $(window);
        cart = $('.mobile-cart');
        var left_offset = cart.position().left;
        var width = $(window).width();

        if(viewport.scrollTop() > cartTop){
            cart.addClass('fixed-cart');
            cart.css('margin-left', '-' + left_offset + 'px');
            cart.css('width', width + 'px');
        } else {
            cart.removeClass('fixed-cart');
            cart.css({'margin-left': 0, 'width': ''});
        }
    }
```

And here is the CSS...

```
    .fixed-cart {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
```

**Android**
The scroll to fix works just fine for the first few hundred pixels of scrolling but then it hits a certain point and then fixed div just scrolls up the page with the rest of the content.

**iOS**
The scroll to fix works but as the user scrolls the fixed div slowly starts to slide up the page until it's out of site.

If I go into web inspector when debugging in Chrome using the device testing, and set the top position to some positive integer I can usually get the div back into view, but I shouldn't have to do this as top: 0 should make the div at the top of the view. What's going on??

Comment: Do you receive any console errors?

Comment: @Greg Nope, no errors...

Answer (score 0):

So I just fixed it by wrapping all my content inside of a div (just below the body tag) with this css

```
position:relative;
min-height: 100%;
```

Anyone know why this fixed it?